# javascript: assign object function return value to object property

Tags: javascript

When I try to assign `getUnit`'s return value to the `inputUnit` property, my script throws the error "this.getUnit is not a function". Can anyone help?

```
function ConvertHandler(initialString) {

  this.inputUnit = this.getUnit(initialString); // Error here
  this.inputNum = this.getNum(initialString);
  this.returnedUnit = this.getReturnUnit(this.inputUnit);
  this.returnedNum = this.convert();

  this.getNum = function(input) {
    return input.match(/((\d*\.?\d+)*(\/?)(\d*\.?\d+))/igm);
  };

  this.getUnit = function(input) {
    return input.match(/[A-Za-z]+$/i);
  };
}

var a = new ConvertHandler('4mi');
console.log(a.spellOutUnit());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to invoke the method before you've defined it.

The assignment succeeds if the order is reversed, as in this snippet:

```js
function ConvertHandler(initialString) {
  this.getNum = function(input) {
    return input.match(/((\d*\.?\d+)*(\/?)(\d*\.?\d+))/igm);
  };
  this.getUnit = function(input) {
    return input.match(/[A-Za-z]+$/i);
  };
  this.inputUnit = this.getUnit(initialString);
  this.inputNum = this.getNum(initialString);
}

var a = new ConvertHandler('4mi');
console.log(a.inputNum);
console.log(a.inputUnit)
```

Comment: as an explanation:
I thought I was having a misunderstanding in js oop, but in fact, this relates to func hoisting,
if I did declare the functions, as "function getUnit (...){....}" it would have worked I guess because of the hoisting func, but I won't be able to access the function as an object property.